# INS-30131 Initial setup required for the execution of installer validations failed

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

i just uninstall oracle 12c manually on windows 10 and now am reinstalling it shows errors:

---

> Cause - Failed to access the temporary location. Action - Ensure that
>   the current user has required permissions to access the temporary
>   location. Additional Information:
>    - Framework setup check failed on all the nodes
>    - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
>    - Action: User Action Not Available Summary of the failed nodes desktop-81i87ss 
>    - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "desktop-81i87ss"  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available 
>    - Action: User Action Not Available

---

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, there is a possibility that your computer name contains some special character, unique installer throws same error in that case. Try removing any special character by renaming your system to a new name and then try installation again.

For Example: My system had name "LAPTOP-GENCONIAN". Problem was solved for me after renaming to "GENCONIAN"

Answer (score 0):

I come across similar issue and was able to resolve with this method

1. Open CMD
2. CD into the folder in which  setup file exits

3.Run the command -   setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"

4. Now the intallation window will open without validation check and you can continue